# how can i use more than one tflite flutter model?

Tags: flutter, dart

i created one tflite model. i want to pass string to model and label according to user selection.
for example, if your select model1 it will load model two, if user select model 2 it load model 2.
in this scnerio, I don't want to create 2 models, I just want to change model and label string on runtime using if else condition.
i am unable to wet set condition, can anyone guide me where can i set if condition?

```
loadModel() async {
      await Tflite.loadModel(
        model: "model location here",
        labels: "label location here",
        numThreads: 1,
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a value listenable builder. When `state.value` change, different model is loaded and it works.

```
if (state.value == 1) {
    await Tflite.loadModel(
        model: "assets/tflite_models/model_1.tflite",
        labels: "assets/tflite_models/labels_1.txt");
  } else if (state.value == 2) {
    await Tflite.loadModel(
        model: "assets/tflite_models/model_2.tflite",
        labels: "assets/tflite_models/labels_2.txt");
  } else {
    await Tflite.loadModel(
        model: "assets/tflite_models/model_3.tflite",
        labels: "assets/tflite_models/labels_3.txt");
  }
```